# Where is filter, sorting, and searching done? In the REST Client (Model) or Store?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I understand that flux is this:

1. REST Client API

   1. Pushes data to Action
2. Action
3. Dispatcher
4. Store

But when filtering, sorting, and searching or aggregating data in anyway, how would one handle multiple data sets and make them available for all views (components)?

Also, how do you prevent from the API loading data again, and use the local data instead? Is this included in Flux?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be different interpretations of Flux, and a common one is that data is pushed to a component from a store instead of being pulled by the component. I don't really agree with that interpretation, and my components always pull data from the stores.

Something like this:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadData();
    SomeStore.on('change', this.loadData);
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    SomeStore.off('change', this.loadData);
  },
  loadData() {
    SomeStore.load({params: {...}})
      .then(data => this.setState({data: data}));
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(item => <li>item</li>)}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={SomeAction.add()}>Click me</button>
    );
  }
});
```

`SomeAction.add()` dispatches an event which `SomeStore` listens to, it adds the new thing to it's state, and then emits a `change` event which the component listens to and pulls in the data again.

Comment: I'm sorry this answer doesn't address filtering, searching, or sorting in anyway.

Comment: It adresses it in that the component is free to call any method it wants on the store, since the component pull data from the store instead of having the store push the data to the component. Because of that, the component can request the data in the way it needs it.